# A infinite sequence

Tags: calculus

I have found myself in trouble with this particularly problem. I have tried Cauchy definition but I could not solve the problem out. Some help will be welcome.

Let be {$a_n$} a sequence such that for every n$\in$$\Bbb N$ it is true that $a_n$$\le$2 and $\vert a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}\vert\le \frac18 \vert a^2_{n+1}-a^2_n\vert$.
Prove that {$a_n$} is a converge sequence.

Comment: Is the sequence assumed nonnegative? The result seems to be false otherwise. Consider, e.g. $-4, -5, -6, -7, \ldots$.

Comment: Well the problem do not say that is nonnegative....

Comment: It works if we can assume $|a_n| \leq 2$, but $a_n \leq 2$ is insufficient as the counterexample shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your sequence is a real number sequence problem. This is probably similar to a problem in "Introduction to Real Analysis" problem from Robert G. Bartle or any other elementary Real Analysis book. \

Let me begin with the following equation (I also believe your sequence might be nonnegative) :

$$ |a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}| \leq \frac{1}{8}|a_{n+1} + a_{n}|\,|a_{n+1}-a_{n}|$$
From the assumption $a_{n} \leq 2$ (and nonnegativity), we have
$$ |a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}| \leq \frac{4}{8}\,|a_{n+1}-a_{n}|=\frac{1}{2}\,|a_{n+1}-a_{n}|$$
Now, we will show that this contractive sequence is Cauchy (you might want to look up for the definition of contractive sequence)

Fix $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and WLOG assume $m > n$. Then, we will have
$$|a_{m}-a_{n}|\leq |a_{m}-a_{m-1}|+|a_{m-1}-a_{m-2}|+...+|a_{n+1}-a_{n}|$$
$$|a_{m}-a_{n}|\leq |a_{1}-a_{0}|\bigg(\frac{1}{2^{n}} + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} + ... +\frac{1}{2^{m-1}}\bigg)$$
$$|a_{m}-a_{n}|\leq \frac{1}{2^{n}}|a_{1}-a_{0}|\bigg(1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{2^{m-n-1}} \bigg)$$
$$|a_{m}-a_{n}|\leq \frac{1}{2^{n}}|a_{1}-a_{0}|\frac{1-\frac{1}{2^{m-n-1}}}{1-1/2}$$
$$|a_{m}-a_{n}|\leq \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}|a_{1}-a_{0}|$$
Taking the limit of $n \to \infty$ we will have for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for any $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $m,n>N$, $|a_{m}-a_{n}|<\varepsilon$